# Ryzen 7 5700G RX Vega 8 not recognized

Tags: 20.04, amd-ryzen, integrated

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 in a computer with a Ryzen 7 5700g, which comes with a RX Vega 8 integrated. The computer work fine for the basic tasks I have performed already, but when checking Settings > About, it shows: "Graphics: AMD® Renoir", instead of the Vega 8, or at least Cezanne.

I'm trying to find the drivers to correct this, but without success.

Edit:

Kernel version

```
$ uname -r
5.13.0-37-generic
```

Comment: Why do you believe that it's not recognized? If you are able to use a desktop environment, then it's working

Comment: I understand your point, but why it shows the wrong model?

Comment: I've checked AMD website and the codename for the 5700G is Cezanne. Renoir was the codename for the 4000 series. https://www.amd.com/en/products/apu/amd-ryzen-7-5700g

Comment: That may not be important.  Can you edit your question and describe what isn't working?  Is your system fully up-to-date? AMD graphics drivers are supported at the kernel level. If it wasn't working, you wouldn't be able to boot into a desktop

Comment: I've installed Ubuntu yesterday and up to this moment, everything works. I was just checking the system and noticed this specification is not matching the actual hardware.

Comment: What kernel are you on? What does `uname -r` output?

Comment: added info to the question

Comment: If you're on kernel 5.13 on 20.04 then that shows you are on the HWE stack which means you have the latest Ubuntu kernel made for your release and the AMD graphics drivers are supported at the kernel level. There isn't an alternative driver that you should try to install. If you aren't actually experiencing any problems, then it's possible that the only problem is the name of the driver. I suggest filing a [bug report](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121) so that developers are aware of the issue. If you do encounter any specific problems, I suggest to ask about that separately

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the drivers are already in the kernel.
Alternatively, you can download the installer for Radeon drivers here:

https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-22-20

Whatever is shown in about does not have to be Vega, it might well be as you see now.
You can check dmesg and lscpi for example to see if it is loaded.

For example :

```
dmesg | grep -i amd
```

You may need sudo in front of that in recent Ubuntu versions.